# Unable to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Hi I have tried both the methods of upgrading.

1. Via terminal, I have typed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update.
   sudo apt-get distr-upgrade.
   sudo do-release-upgrade
   ```

   But failed to upgrade distribution. It's showing error as:

   ```
   The required dependency 'apt (>= 1.0.1ubuntu2.13)'is not installed.
   ```
2. When I opened update manager, it shows certain security updates but when I clicked install, it is unable to download, showing an internet connection error. Actually my internet is working at good 3G speed.

Please help me with upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in a Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get -y install apt
sudo do-release-upgrade
```